Calculate the segment $AC$ in the quarilateral $ABCD$ below
Calculate $CQ$ if $AB = 4$, $AD = 6$ and $AB∥CM$.
(Answer:$1$)

I try:
$\angle CDA = 90^o-\theta$
$\angle ACM = \theta \therefore \triangle ACM_{(isosc.)} \implies CM = AM$
$\angle DMC = 2\theta $
$\angle MCD = 90^o - \theta$
$\therefore \triangle DMC_{(isosc.)}: DM=MC=AM = 3$

I would suggest, better mention in the question statement $\angle BAC=\angle CAD$

You've done all the work. Observe that

$MQ = AB/2 = 2$
$CQ = CM - QM = 1$.


Thanks for help

You have verified that $M$ is the midpoint of $AC$, then by similar triangle, we have  $$BQ:QD=1:1$$ By angle bisector theorem, if we set $X$ to be the intersection of $AC$ and $BD$, we have $$BX:XD=4:6$$
Combining two ratios gives $BX:XQ:QD=4:1:5$. By similar triangle again, $$CQ:AB=XQ:QB=1:4$$
This gives $CQ=1$.

Thanks for help
